# SxS installations and WiX

Tags: installation, wix, winsxs, sxs

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with installation and deployment of our project which is a framework. Typically developers would install the framework and then have their .Net applications reference our dlls.

The framework has 2 levels:

1. A number of native C++ dlls
2. Some C++\CLI and C# assemblies (all are dlls) that reference the native dlls

I want to provide an installer that puts the .Net assemblies in the GAC and installs the native assemblies in the WinSxS folder. So far I haven't been able to find much info about installing SxS assemblies. I know it can be done using MSI, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to do it with WiX or with some other installer tool.

I believe this cannot be done using the Visual Studio setup projects.

Answer (score 5):

I did a search in the wix mailing pile and "[Tutorial: How to install files into WinSxS](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Tutorial-How-to-install-files-into-WinSxS-td841475.html)" came up. Hope it's helpful to you.